# jQuery prompt not closing after clicking close button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've gotten this to work on all my other pages, and I have copied the code from there, (other developers developed this) and it has worked no problem. I switched to a newer jQuery (1.10) and now the close is not closing the prompt.

```
function DialogPrompt(url, height, width, onload_method, complete_method) {
        $("<div id=\"prompt\"><img src='/js/loadingAnimation.gif' /></div>")
                .dialog({
                    modal: true, height: height, width: width,
                    buttons: {
                        "Close": function () {
                            // Close the dialog
                            $(this).dialog("close").remove();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Before the close button was pressed:
[image]

After the close button was pressed:
[image]

as you can see that the details of the prompt were closed but the prompt still remains

So before I get flagged for not asking a question:

How do I fix this? Is there something wrong with my syntax? is there something wrong with the close for the new jQuery?

Also, these are my updated jQuery files:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="/css/ui/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

all updated from the .min files from their website

new error that I got in the console after changing the URL of the prompt being passed in..
"Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'"

this is baffling.. its the only page that this doesnt work on...

Comment: On "Close": function () {..., after $(this).dialog("close").remove();,  could you include "return true" or return the command to close the modal?

Comment: `.dialog("close");` is exactly what I always use (I don't use `remove()` as I reuse dialogs, rather than build them on-the-fly).

Comment: i removed the .remove(); and tried with just .dialog("close"); and it didn't do anything

Comment: As `.dialog()` is from jQuery-ui, did you update that too?

Comment: updated with my resource calls to the UI and css update as well

Comment: Any errors in console? as mentioned above, you should get rid of `.remove()`

Comment: No errors in console, I even stepped through it with the google dev debugger.. I removed the .remove() and nothing happens at all

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with this code to reproduce the same problem ?

Comment: well I can't because I'm using an external URL to pass in for the prompt.  It would be a bigger hassle to make the fiddle project for it.  I just rewrote the prompt to have the div for the prompt on the page and that worked. It seems that is has something to do with ASP page.. I am really not sure.. However this issue is "resolved" or at least worked around.